# what is intersection of two set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ ‎X=C[-1,1]‎$ be‎‎ and $M, N $ are the subspaces defined by
‎$$ ‎M= ‎‎\left\{f‎  \in ‎X\mid ‎f(t)=0 ,‎  ‎t \in [-1, 0] \right\}, ‎$$
$$  ‎N= ‎‎\left\{g \in ‎X\mid ‎g(t)=0 ,‎  ‎‎t \in [0,1]\right\}.$$ 
What are $ M \cap N \text{ and }M + N$?

Comment: When you write $M+N$, in what context do you mean that?

Comment: I want to see if $ M \bigoplus N =X ?$

Comment: To see that simply take any function in $X$ and see if you can write it as a sum of two functions from $M$ and from $N$. Can you do that for the function $f(t)=1$?

Comment: so $ M \bigoplus N \neq X$ ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $h\in M\cap N$ then for every $t\in[-1,0]$, $h(t)=0$ and for every $t\in[0,1]$, $h(t)=0$.

**Hint II:** Show that if $f\in M+N$ then $f(0)=0$, and conclude that $M\oplus N\neq X$.

**Hint III:** Show that if $h(0)=0$ then you can write $h$ as the sum of $f\in M$ and $g\in N$.

Conclude what is $M\oplus N$ from the second and third hints. They give sufficient and necessary conditions for a function to be in the sum.

Comment: And one can even determine $M+N$...

Comment: Did: Please try to determine $ M+N= ?$

Comment: @nim Well, to begin with, any $f$ in $M+N$ should be such that $f(0)=0$, right? But is $f(0)=0$ sufficient for $f$ to be in $M+N$? Not quite, since every function in $M+N$ should be $C^1$. So, $M+N$ is in fact...

Comment: @nim Oh, and please use `@name` to signal your comments, not just `name`.

Comment: @nim: That can't be right. Note that $x\mapsto|x|$ is in $M+N$. It is the sum of $x\mapsto\begin{cases}-x &x<0\\0& x\geq 0\end{cases}$ and $x\mapsto\begin{cases}0 & x<0\\x& x\geq 0\end{cases}$. The absolute value is not $C^1$.

Comment: @Did: Why do functions in the the sum have to be $C^1$?

Comment: @Asaf Oddly, I got convinced that $X$ was made of $C^1$ functions. Apparently this was never mentioned by the OP. Thus, my previous comment is ridiculous. Sorry about that (maybe I should slow down on coffee...).

Comment: @Did: Maybe you need to add more coffee to the mix. I often found that beer (or perhaps wine?) works well to take the edge off the over-caffeinated mind. It will get you slammed out by the after noon, though.

Comment: @nim Asaf is giving you everything you need to determine $M+N$. This is more constructive than stating "yes $M+N=X$" or "no $M+N\ne X$".

Comment: @nim: What do you mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm sorry. I need to have time to think on this question.

Comment: @nim: How many functions are there such that $h(t)=0$ for *all* $t\in[-1,1]$? No, that is not the final answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Only the zero constant function? ( for $ t=0$)

Comment: @nim: Only the zero function has that for **every** $t$, $h(t)=0$. So the sum of two non-zero spaces are clearly not just the zero function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: please Just say me, so $ M + N \neq X $? this is question of my phd exam and I am uneasy about this question. thanks

Comment: @nim: I already told you *almost* everything. If you really think that you can handle a Ph.D. in mathematics then you should be able to figure it out from the hints in my answer above.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I am not sure of the answer. Otherwise clear

Comment: @nim: No, it seems that not everything is clear. Because if it were, the answer would have been obvious.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: $ M + N = \{f\in X : f(0)=0\}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:It was an interesting discussion. thanks Asaf

Comment: @nim: Yes, that is correct. I am happy that you enjoyed!

Comment: @Did: Do you hope that nim would just magically come by and read your comment, or do you plan on pinging the user as well? :-)

Comment: @Asaf I thought the user asking a question was pinged for every comment on every answer their question received. Since you imply this is not the case, I will repost my comment, pinging the OP.

Comment: @nim For those unfamiliar with the system, what is a "PhD exam"? An exam one has to pass before being allowed to prepare a PhD?

Comment: @nim (Thanks for the information.) Well, then I am surprised by the level of the question. Is this for a PhD in pure maths?

Comment: As I already hinted at, the question in your post is rather elementary. Now, perhaps this is only one item in a larger set of, somewhat more involved, questions, which would globally make for a more substantial test. (Unrelated: please use `@name` to signal a comment to user `name`, especially if you are anxious to get an answer.)

Comment: @nim Why did you delete (at least) two comments of yours--especially one about which you declared to be quite anxious to get an answer?